# Adding Decimal to a String in Javascript

Tags: javascript, string, rounding

I'm given numbers in cents:

eg.

```
  102042
  982123
  121212
```

I want to convert them to dollars. I figured the easiest way to do this is to convert the digits into a string and add a decimal.

eg.

```
  1020.42
  9821.23
  1212.12
```

I'm currently doing this but it only rounds to 1 decimal. What would I need to do it make it round to 2 decimals?

```
var number = 102042
number.toString().match(/^-?\d+(?:\.\d{0,2})?/)[0]
```

UPDATE: I found out what my issue was. It wasn't the rounding but the fact that I combined a lodash filter to a division incorrectly. Thanks again!

Comment: `number = number / 100`

Comment: I hate maths too

Comment: `(number / 100).toFixed(2)`

Comment: @JaromandaX I had this before but it wasn't working

Comment: really? what was it doing instead?

Comment: @JaromandaX wow, my bad, I had a typo! That works now

Comment: In case you don't trust the accuracy of floating-point numbers: `String(number).replace(/..$/, '.$&')`

Answer (score 3):

A cent is 1/100th of a dollar, so you can calculate the dollar amount by doing

```
dollars = number / 100
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
var number = 102042;

console.log(number/100);
```

Comment: `102040` would not print the 100ths place.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to do it with the number itself, you can multiply by 0.01 or divide by 100 and you'll get that amount in dollars:

```js
var numbers = [102042,982123,121212];

for(num of numbers) 
  console.log(num/100);
```